# PayPal REST API Get Authorization Code returned from credit card processor

Tags: rest, api, paypal, credit-card

There is a [code returned by the credit card processor](https://cayan.com/glossary/authorization-code) when the transaction is approved, usually 5-6 digits. I'm trying to retrieve this code with REST API in their sandbox.

If you are using PayPal Payflow you can see this on the [transaction result page](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/perform_transaction_result.htm) when logged in to your Payflow account. This number is also on a printed receipt when you go to a store, it's a very common number to have after an approved CC payment. I have yet to accept a real payment through REST API, just working with sandbox so far. Looking at the response for the sandbox payment and the sale transaction I cannot see anything that looks like the processor authorization code.

Documentation for this authorization code is difficult to research and I don't want to lead anyone astray; **I'm not looking for anything related to the auth code used for access and refresh tokens, same name but completely different.**